# Accurate memory usage estimate of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, windows, pandas, memory

I discovered a mismatch between memory usage reported by pandas and python, and actual memory usage of a python process reported by the OS (Windows, in my case).

After I import numpy, pandas and some other standard libs (like os, sys), RAM consumption of the own process, reported psutil and consistent with Task Manger, equals **89 020 K**.

Then I create example dataframe consisting of both object and numerical dtypes like this:

```py
    l=5_000_000
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(-100,100,size=l), columns=list('A'))
    df['B']='dsgdb9nsdalWofsT'
    df['C']=np.random.randint(0,130000,size=l).astype(np.int64)
    df['D']=np.random.randint(0,130000,size=l).astype(np.int64)
    df['E']='2JHH'
```

After creating the dataframe psutil reports **286 696 K** (again, consistent with the Windows Task Manager).

When running df.info() I get

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

RangeIndex: 5000000 entries, 0 to 4999999
Data columns (total 5 columns):
A    float64
B    object
C    int64
D    int64
E    object
dtypes: float64(1), int64(2), object(2)
memory usage: 190.7+ MB
```

which is very logical so far.

Now, let's get

```py
    df.memory_usage(index=True,deep=False).sum()/1024
```

> 195 312.6

And what about

```py
    df.memory_usage(index=True,deep=True).sum()/1024 ?
```

Terrific

> 771 484.5

which I can not explain.

According to pandas' docs,

> Without deep introspection a memory estimation is made based in column
>   dtype and number of rows assuming values consume the same memory
>   amount for corresponding dtypes. With deep memory introspection, a
>   real memory usage calculation is performed at the cost of
>   computational resources.

So we could expect **deep** option to be more precise. **How is it not? What am I missing? Why is it giving wrong results? Is this a feature or a bug?**

I also have to say that python itself gives wrong results when using **sys** module:

```py
    sys.getsizeof(df)/1024
```

> 771 484.52

I am testing using Jupyter notebook server 5.7.4, my specs are

*Python version: 3.7.2 (default, Feb 21 2019, 17:35:59) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]*

*platform: AMD64*

*system: Windows-10-10.0.17763-SP0*

*pandas: 0.25.0*

*numpy: 1.16.2*

Comment: I think this bug is not yet resolved in pandas 1,0.0. Did you find any other way to estimate ?

Comment: nope, I did not (

Answer (score 1):

I ran this with Pandas 1.0.3 and Python 3.7.4 on CentOS 7.  I get the same results.  Seems `df.memory_usage(index=True,deep=True)` and `getsizeof` are both buggy.  If I check `process.memory_info()[0]` (RSS Resident Set Size) before and after the `dataframe` creation, the difference is 191 MB.

Comment: In my experience, the dataframe memory estimates are grossly low when loading large JSON files that have arrays in the JSON objects.  I have an example of a 28 MB JSON file loaded into a Pandas dataframe.  The 'deep' memory usage displays 18 MB, however, the RSS memory consumed is nearly 300 MB.  Python dictionaries and lists appear to have considerable overhead.

Answer (score 1):

I think this post answers this issue well:
https://pythonspeed.com/articles/pandas-dataframe-series-memory-usage/

For short, there are memory optimisation in python implementation that neither pandas nor sys consider in their calculations. Thus, usually, the memory usage reported by these methods is typically higher than actuals.

Comment: So, ~500Mb RAM difference was caused by the interning of 5M 'dsgdb9nsdalWofsT' string instances which .info() and .memory_usage(deep=False) were aware of, and .memory_usage(deep=True) was not?